# How can i make the console app Exit if the user prints 'x' in my C# program?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-console

**I have written a calculator program in C#.**

I want my program to exit (end) if the user enter the character 'x' in my C# console app.

I have tried to use `return;` but I don't get it to work.

Also tried to call `Environment.Exit()` but did not get that to work either.

If anyone has any tips, feel free to share! :)

Here is the code that handle the input from the user:

```
Console.Write("Skriv in en siffra: ");
double firstUserInput;

while (!Double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out firstUserInput))
{
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.Write("Ogiltigt värde, skriv in en siffra: ");
}

while (true)
{
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.Write("Välj räknesätt mellan   + - * /  : ");
    string operators = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.Write("Skriv in en till siffra: ");
    double secondUserInput;

    while (!Double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out secondUserInput))
    {
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.Write("Ogiltigt värde, skriv in en siffra: ");

    }
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine();


    switch (operators)
    {
        case "+":
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Svar: " + firstUserInput + " + " + secondUserInput + " = " + (firstUserInput + secondUserInput));
            firstUserInput = (firstUserInput + secondUserInput);
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine();

            break;
        case "-":
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Svar: " + firstUserInput + " - " + secondUserInput + " = " + (firstUserInput - secondUserInput));
            firstUserInput = (firstUserInput - secondUserInput);
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine();

            break;
        case "*":
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Svar: " + firstUserInput + " * " + secondUserInput + " = " + (firstUserInput * secondUserInput));
            firstUserInput = (firstUserInput * secondUserInput);
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine();

            break;
        case "/":
            if (secondUserInput == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Går inte att dividera med 0, försök igen!");
                Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Svar: " + firstUserInput + " / " + secondUserInput + " = " + (firstUserInput / secondUserInput));
                firstUserInput = (firstUserInput / secondUserInput);
                Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Have you tried debbuging ? It feels weird that none of your solution worked, maybe you never get to the point where you exited ?

Comment: Your code shows no handling for `x` - where is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear how your `Main` method implemented but you should be able to call `Environment.Exit` to exit the application at any time, e.g.:

```
const string Exit = "x";
string line = Console.ReadLine();
while (!Double.TryParse(line, out firstUserInput))
{
    if (string.Compare(line, Exit, true) == 0)
        System.Environment.Exit(0);

    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.Write("Ogiltigt värde, skriv in en siffra: ");
}

while (true)
{
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.Write("Välj räknesätt mellan   + - * /  : ");
    string operators = Console.ReadLine();
    if (string.Compare(operators, Exit, true) == 0)
        System.Environment.Exit(0);
    Console.Write("Skriv in en till siffra: ");
    double secondUserInput;

    line = Console.ReadLine();
    while (!Double.TryParse(line, out secondUserInput))
    {
        if (string.Compare(line, Exit, true) == 0)
            System.Environment.Exit(0);

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.Write("Ogiltigt värde, skriv in en siffra: ");

    }
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine();
    ...
```

Comment: `if (string.Compare(firstUserInput, Exit, true) == 0)
        System.Environment.Exit(0);`   I get an error for firstUserInput that says: Argument 1 cannot convert from double to string?

Comment: @Emil: Right, you need to compare the value returned from `Console.ReadLine()`. See my edit.

Comment: With a few adjustments it worked like a charm! Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

I dont see any handlings including 'x'.

You could implement maybe something like this:

```
string str = Console.ReadLine();
if(str.Equals("x"))    // Note that this is case sensitive
{
  Enviroment.Exit(0);
}
```

And then you can lets say add your TryParse block of code.